# Data to display from 2 different table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different tables in my database.

For eg; In table 1, named `table1` , it has the following data:

```
||===============================||
|| ID            |       DATE    ||
===================================
|| 1             |      2nd Jan  ||
===================================
|| 2             |      4th Apr  ||
===================================
```

And lets say in table 2, named `table2`, it has the following data:

```
||===============================||
|| ID            |       NAME    ||
===================================
|| 1             |       John    ||
===================================
|| 2             |       Pam     ||
===================================
```

Now, both these table's **(ID) is NOT THE SAME**.

What I want to display is:

```
||===============================||===============================||
|| ID            |       NAME    ||        ID      |   DATE       ||
====================================================================
|| 1             |       John    ||         NULL   |   NULL       || 
====================================================================
|| 2             |       Pam     ||         NULL   |   NULL       ||
====================================================================
|| NULL          |       NULL    ||          1    |    2nd Jan    ||
====================================================================
|| NULL          |       NULL    ||          2    |    4th Apr    ||
====================================================================
```

So what I tried these mySQL statements:

`select a.id, a.date, b.id, b.name from table1 a, table2 b`

But this doesn't give me  the correct display, it combines the result.

I also tried `left join`, it also combines the results.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: is there any relation between both tables ?

Comment: If there is no relation between the two tables, why you want to show result in a combined table. If your requirement says so, then you could store all the data in same table.

Comment: if I were you I'd build the table in the front end. Query table A, Query table B. Fetch both result arrays. Loop the first (last columns empty), loop the second (first columns empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.date, NULL id, NULL name  from table1 a
UNION ALL
select NULL id, NULL date, b.id, b.name from table2 b
```

Just try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with a 'fake' outer join:

```
select  a.id, a.date, b.id, b.name
from    table1 a
full outer join
        table2 b
on      1 = 0;
```